# How do I let users send and receive email using Gmail in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail, gmail-api

For my application I have users that I would like to be able to send and receive emails inside of the application itself. I am wanting to integrate Gmail for this purpose because I already have OAuth2 authentication integrated.

I have gone through the process of creating the Google App, getting the correct credentials, setting up OAuth2, getting their token etc.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to talk to the Gmail API and use it in order to be able to send and receive emails using it for specific users within the application.

I have found several gems such as gmail_xoauth and gmail-ruby-api which look as though I may have to implement them first, but I am not sure how or what to do in orde r to do so.

I am new to rails and a bit confused, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://markgandolfo.com/blog/2016/01/05/gmail-gem-and-omniauth-google-oauth2-setup-in-a-rails-app/) explaining this using the `Gmail` gem and `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem.

With [Gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) gem users can Search, read and send multipart emails, archive, mark as read/unread, delete emails, and manage labels.

This gem has so many handy methods like the one following

```
gmail.inbox.emails(:unread, :before => Date.parse("2010-04-20"), :from => "myboss@gmail.com")
```

documentation is pretty decent with examples for sending, receiving and processing attachments.